# "block decode failed" error while mining in pool

Tags: mining-pools, cgminer

I just started solo mining last month, and I have no problems with cgminer.
I have already shares accepted and sometimes new block detected.
I want to know why when I want decode I've an error?
For example, "block decode failed (-22)"

In my Roaming\Bitcoin\blocks, I have some 300 files who called blk00000.dat and until i'm mining, until the list expand.

But I don't have receive my awards for my blocks.... and not to for the fees...

Can you explain me please?

Is the blocks files are my detected block by mining?
Why I've an error block decode failed? How to do too receive my awards?

Thanks for your  help...

Ps:i'm french and i say "il n'y a rien de plus frustrant de ne pas comprendre"
It's like "there is nothing biggest frustation than don't understand!!!"

Comment: Are you using any software besides Bitcoin and cgminer? Are you sure you're solo mining?

Comment: the blk0xxx.dat files are just the blocks that form the blockchain. They are not the blocks you found. Unless you have a LOT of mining power (more than 10,000 ASIC machines, for example), I really doubt you even found 1 block.

Comment: Hello Beliomir: Please, put any additional information **into the question by editing** instead of adding answers to your post.

Answer (score 2):

Are you running "bitcoin-cli submitblock xyz" manually? You are not supposed to do this. Software does this. If you mine in a pool you don't even need to run bitcoind at all.

If you do want to run your own bitcoind node, don't mess with the blk*.dat files. You don't need to touch them. The bitcoind program is the only thing that needs to use them.

If you mine in a pool just set up your ASIC mining machines and make sure they are running, then use the pool website for the rest of your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Good Day,

Are you solo mining or pool mining?

If you are solo mining.... You will need to have about **1000 Th/s of ASIC Cheddar** to Mine Solo. So, that is striked.

If you have that kind of cheddar of a 1000 ASICS, it will take **about a day** for it to come in your account with a couple of confirmations....

To know if you are solo mining you will have a **--btc-address=** and this param should have your BTC Address... if you are solo mining.

If you are pool mining, your parameters will something like **-u somename.worker1 -p password** or **-u BTC_ADDRESS -p x**

It is also **safe** to assume that you **haven't mined a solo block.** with a CPU or GPU

If you are pool mining (duh!), go to that pool's website and login to your account.

Hopefully, you created a worker or else there is a chance that you have mined to donation.... and you didn't make a dime..... If you did, your Username should be your Worker ID `e.g. username.worker1` and Pass to whatever you set...

Then wait for the round of cash complete (Seriously Wait..)..... for hours...

Then go and withdraw your BTC from the pool to your wallet address and enjoy this tiny (I guess...) wealth.

If you are using **Eligius or a Non-Registratable P2P Pool** then your Username **Should** be your BitCoin Address and Your Password Being `x` or `123`.

Same applies here, if you don't put a Version 0 Address, (i.e. An Address starting with `1`) or put some other rubbish other than **YOUR** address, it goes for donations....

Your worker password cannot be used for accessing your bits.

**Also that blk(whatever...).dat is the records of other cash, that is the BlockChain!**

Comment: Thank's for your answer... Surely i use two asics miners in usb connect, the last version of cgminer can use asics in usb... I'm not liying, i have all the time, some share accpeted and sometimes i have new block detected. I've found on the net, that the lastest version of bitcoin-qt doesn't mining??? really??? I use a pool, which i can solo mining by user=adress wallet and pass=wathyouwant When i write getblocktemplate i have a list of block transaction and shares and fees...

Comment: When i submit a block with submitblock =>block decode failed.

Thank's for your answer, but the mining pool that i use, can solo and there is develloped for low power mining....

I can't understand why?

I understood that blk00000.dat is the blockchain. First block that creator have been created in a first time.